# JavaFX how to trigger events on Geometries?

Tags: java, javafx, geometry, shapes

I'm writting an JavaFX application, where i use UTM32 coordinates for my geometries, i have a dynamic stroke width dependent on my zoom level. The issue is that i can't trigger events when my stroke width is decreased at a certain factor. If you use Intellij you can start a new fx-project and copy following code to reproduce this behaviour:

**hello-view.fxml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.geometry.Insets?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.Pane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.VBox?>
<VBox alignment="CENTER" prefHeight="248.0" prefWidth="335.0" spacing="20.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/11.0.2"
      xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="com.example.demo.HelloController">
    <padding>
        <Insets bottom="20.0" left="20.0" right="20.0" top="20.0"/>
    </padding>
    <Pane fx:id="mapPane" prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="200.0">
        <children>
            <StackPane fx:id="stackPane" prefHeight="150.0" prefWidth="200.0">
            </StackPane>
        </children>
    </Pane>
</VBox>
```

***HelloApplication.java***

```
package com.example.demo;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import java.io.IOException;

public class HelloApplication extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws IOException {
        FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(HelloApplication.class.getResource("hello-view.fxml"));
        Scene scene = new Scene(fxmlLoader.load(), 320, 240);
        stage.setTitle("Hello!");
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch();
    }
}
```

**HelloController.java**

```
package com.example.demo;

import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent;
import javafx.scene.input.ScrollEvent;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.Line;
import javafx.scene.shape.Shape;

import java.net.URL;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;

public class HelloController implements Initializable {
    private final Group mapGroup = new Group();
    @FXML
    private StackPane stackPane = new StackPane();
    @FXML
    public Pane mapPane;
    double mouseAnchorX, mouseAnchorY, translateAnchorX, translateAnchorY;

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
        addLines();
        stackPane.getChildren().add(mapGroup);
        mapPane.setOnScroll(onMouseScrolledEventHandler());
        mapPane.setOnMousePressed(onMousePressedEventHandler());
    }

    private void addLines() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
            Line line = new Line(getRandomDouble(5000000, 5000002), getRandomDouble(5000000, 5000002),
                    getRandomDouble(5000000, 5000002), getRandomDouble(5000000, 5000002));
            line.addEventHandler(MouseEvent.MOUSE_PRESSED, onShapeSelected());
            (line).setSmooth(true);
            mapGroup.getChildren().add(line);
        }
    }

    private double getRandomDouble(double rangeMin, double rangeMax) {
        Random rand = new Random();
        return rangeMin + (rangeMax - rangeMin) * rand.nextDouble();
    }

    private EventHandler<MouseEvent> onShapeSelected() {
        return mouseEvent -> {
            if (!mouseEvent.isPrimaryButtonDown()) {
                return;
            }
            System.out.println("Event triggered");
            ((Shape) mouseEvent.getSource()).setStroke(Color.RED);
        };
    }

    public void decreaseStrokeWidth(double val) {
        for (Node shape : mapGroup.getChildren()) {
            ((Shape) shape).setStrokeWidth(val);
        }
    }

    private EventHandler<MouseEvent> onMousePressedEventHandler() {
        return event -> {
            if (event.isPrimaryButtonDown()) {
                if (!event.getPickResult().getIntersectedNode().getParent().equals(mapGroup)) {
                    for (Node shape : mapGroup.getChildren()) {
                        ((Shape) shape).setStroke(Color.BLACK);
                    }
                }
            }
            if (event.isSecondaryButtonDown()) {
                mouseAnchorX = event.getSceneX();
                mouseAnchorY = event.getSceneY();
                translateAnchorX = mapGroup.getTranslateX();
                translateAnchorY = mapGroup.getTranslateY();
            }
        };
    }

    private EventHandler<ScrollEvent> onMouseScrolledEventHandler() {
        return event -> {
            double scale = mapGroup.getScaleY();
            double oldScale = scale;
            scale = event.getDeltaY() < 0 ? (scale / 1.1) : (scale * 1.1);
            double dx = (event.getSceneX() - (mapGroup.getBoundsInParent().getWidth() / 2 + mapGroup.getBoundsInParent().getMinX()));
            double dy = (event.getSceneY() - (mapGroup.getBoundsInParent().getHeight() / 2 + mapGroup.getBoundsInParent().getMinY()));
            double f = (scale / oldScale) - 1;
            mapGroup.setScaleX(scale);
            mapGroup.setScaleY(scale);
            mapGroup.setTranslateX(mapGroup.getTranslateX() - f * dx);
            mapGroup.setTranslateY(mapGroup.getTranslateY() - f * dy);
            decreaseStrokeWidth(Math.max(1 / scale, 0.2)); // Change this parameter
            event.consume();
        };
    }
}
```

You can change the coordinate range of the lines and the strokewidth. Now can anyone explain this beaviour to me and can give me some suggestions how to deal with this issue. I really wan't to find a workaround for this, but my guess is that it has something to do with internal interpolation.

Comment: To make this mre usebale I believe `@FXML private StackPane stackPane = new StackPane();` should be `@FXML private StackPane stackPane;`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's why I often don't use event handlers directly on geometries. Instead I add a single event handler to the pane and when a event happens I iterate over my geometries manually. Especially for very thin lines, which are always difficult to hit exactly with the mouse, I test whether the geometry intersects a little rectangle defined around the event location. That way I could even select invisible lines without problem :-) This procedure is also helpful for more complex selection schemes, e.g., if you want to have a list of all possible selection candidates etc.

Comment: That's an approach i thought about as well, i was hoping there is a simpler way around this. But of course, i could just pick the nearest geometry in an bounding area which is predefined. Complexity should be fine as well since it's O(n), even tho i need to display a lot of geometries in my case. Anyways, mabe someone else can explain this or has an better approach. Thanks anyways

Comment: In the most simple case this would be just looping over your geometries and test whether they intersect a say 10x10 pixel large rectangle around the clicked mouse position. The JavaFX geometries already provide the methods to do this test. The concept can later be refined to first test against the bounding boxes or even use a spatial index.

Comment: I will try this approach, seems the best workaround for now and shouldn't be hard to implement. I'll let you know

Comment: Worked just fine, i implemented an algorithm which calculates the shortest distance between the mouseclick and the boundaries of the relevant shapes. Thanks for your suggestion